# AWS: Failed to create load balancer: An unknown error occurred

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am trying to create a load balancer using EC2 dashboard on AWS. I have all the information exactly as mentioned in this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-increase-availability.html). In the final step when I click on `create` button, It throws `Failed to create load balancer: An unknown error occurred`. I am not sure what I am missing here. Also, I have `ElasticLoadBalancingFullAccess`. I am attaching a screenshot of the page on which I am facing this issue. Can someone please help me with resolving this issue?

[Load Balancer Creation Status Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oPRj.png)

Comment: AWS has some issues right now. Maybe related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62341775/aws-create-role-rate-exceeded).

Answer (score 0):

This was an internal AWS issue. It was resolved automatically after some time.