# Cannot create new AWS IAM role. Getting "Rate exceeded" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Started to explore AWS and stuck with problem. Trying to create new IAM role using AWS website and get the same error

"An error occurred
Your request has a problem. Please see the following details.
Rate exceeded"

Here is short cURL request of creating new IAM role.

```
  curl 'https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/api/roles' \

  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
  like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'Origin: https://console.aws.amazon.com' \
  -H 'Referer: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=eu-central-1' \
  --data-binary '{"name":"AWSServiceRoleForAmazonElasticsearchService","description":"Allows 
  EC2 instances to call AWS services on your behalf.","trustPolicyDocument":" 
  {\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Action\": 
  [\"sts:AssumeRole\"],\"Principal\":{\"Service\": 
  [\"ec2.amazonaws.com\"]}}]}","scopeArn":null,"tags":[]}' \
```

Response

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Rate exceeded","code":"Throttling","httpStatus":400,"__type__":"ErrorMessage"}]}
```

What kind of rate did exceed? Where can i find limits for this rate?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: How many roles do you have in your AWS account?

Comment: CHeck here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62341775/aws-create-role-rate-exceeded

Comment: @MattiaCostamagna only 7 roles. 
Found out that some other guys also got the same problem today
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62341775/aws-create-role-rate-exceeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to an ongoing incident.

> We have identified the root cause of the increased error rates and latencies on the AWS IAM CreateRole and CreateServiceLinkedRole APIs and are working towards resolution. Other AWS services such as AWS CloudFormation whose features require these actions may also be impacted. User authentications and authorizations are not impacted.

You can view the progress [here](https://status.aws.amazon.com/).

The suggestion is to try again

Comment: Glad I can help